# Each workspace with their own launchers and folders

Tags: unity, directory, workspaces

I have 4 workspaces configured on compiz . I would like to know if there is a way to have folders exclusively in the main desktop (1)? I would like to keep the others clear to see wallpapers.

Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Comment: Well, *effectively*, something is possible, similar to this http://askubuntu.com/a/582569/72216. I can "convert" it to Unity. Let me know if that would be interesting to you.

Comment: I am still trying to use the script . But the answer is yes ,it is what i am looking for.

Comment: The script there will definitely not work with Unity :) I will convert it to Unity Tomorrow!

Comment: Hi Elias, added the launchers-per-workspace option. Just an idea,  but having a distinguished Unity launcher per workspace would be a relatively small addition. It wouldn't make the script any heavier for the system (if any), since it only acts on workspace *change*. Would that add anything to it for you?

Comment: @ Jacob Vlijm Have done this ?   http://www.webupd8.org/2015/04/organize-your-unity-launcher-based-on.html

Comment: Yeah, that's it. the GUI turned out to be more work than the script :)

Comment: @ Jacob Vlijm  The lswitcher is not working anymore with ubuntu 16.04 . Can you fix it ?

Comment: Hi Elias, definitely, I will look at it and will leave a message.

Comment: Hi Elias, my bad, I thought I had copied all my ppa's to Xenial, but I didn't. I just did however. Please try again now, the package is copied to Xenial now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is an edited version of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/582569/72216), but with the difference that this one is for Unity (instead of XFCE) and is to manage a set of (links to) *folders* per workspace, instead of application launchers. However, by uncommenting a line (see further below), you can also set a different set of application launchers per workspace at the same time.

The fact that it is for Unity makes the script slightly more complicated, but in principle, it works pretty much exactly the same.

An example:

*workspace 1:*

[image]

*workspace 2 (3, 4):*

[image]

#### How to make folders available in a workspace- specific way

In the solution below, not the actual folders appear on your desktop (or only on one of the workspaces, or any of your choice), but *links* to a (any) folder. From your comment I understand that is an acceptable solution to you.
This makes it *effectively* possible to have a (virtual) folder on one workspace, but not on another. A background script keeps track of the current workspace and changes the set of links on your desktop, according to how you set it up.

#### How to set up

1. The script uses `wmctrl` to get information on the current workspace:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. In your home directory (not in a subdirectory, but on the "first" level), create a directory (exactly) named:

   ```
   desktop_data
   ```

   inside this directory, create for each of your (in this example four) desktops, a folder named (exactly):

   ```
   desktop_1
   desktop_2
   desktop_3
   desktop_4
   ```

   [image]
3. In these folders, create links to all folders that you want to appear on the corresponding desktop. If, for example, you want the folder `Documents` to appear on viewport (workspace) 1, create a link:

   ```
   ln -s ~/Documents ~/desktop_data/desktop_1/Documents
   ```

   and so on, for all folders you want to appear on the targeted desktop(s):

   [image]

   **NB** If you also want a set of launchers per desktop, add the launchers to the folder and make them executable (!).
4. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `change_desktop.py`. Test-run it by running in a terminal window the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/change_desktop.py
   ```

   Switch workspaces like you use to do since the script acts on switching workspaces.

   **NB** if you also want a set of launchers, specific to the different workspaces, uncomment the line:

   ```
   if os.path.islink(subject) or subject.endswith(".desktop"):
   ```

   but *make sure* the line:

   ```
   # if os.path.islink(subject):
   ```

   is commented out (put a `#` in front of the line)

In the example above, the folders `Documents`, `Netwerkmap` and `screen_notes` appear on workspace 1, but not on workspace 2 (3,4)

If all works fine, add it to your startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import time
import shutil

home = os.environ["HOME"]
desktop_dir = home+"/"+"Bureaublad"
data_dirstr = home+"/desktop_data/desktop_"

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8")

# get resolution
xr = get("xrandr").split()
plus = 2 if xr[xr.index("connected")+1] == "primary" else 1
res = [int(n) for n in xr[xr.index("connected")+plus].split("+")[0].split("x")]

def get_dt():
    # get the current viewport
    vp_data = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-d"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    dt = [int(n) for n in vp_data[3].split("x")]
    cols = int(dt[0]/res[0])
    curr_vpdata = [int(n) for n in vp_data[5].split(",")]
    curr_col = int(curr_vpdata[0]/res[0])+1; curr_row = int(curr_vpdata[1]/res[1])
    return str(curr_col+curr_row*cols)

curr_dt1 = get_dt()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    curr_dt2 = get_dt()
    # alter the set of links when workspace changes
    if not curr_dt1 == curr_dt2:
        datafolder = data_dirstr+curr_dt2
        for f in os.listdir(desktop_dir):
            subject = desktop_dir+"/"+f
            # uncomment one of the two lines below
            if os.path.islink(subject):                                       # uncomment for only folders (links to) per workspace
            # if os.path.islink(subject) or subject.endswith(".desktop") :    # uncomment for folders and .desktop files per workspace
            #
                os.remove(subject)
        for f in os.listdir(datafolder):
            subject = datafolder+"/"+f; target = desktop_dir+"/"+f
            if os.path.islink(subject):
                os.symlink(os.readlink(subject), target)
            else:
                shutil.copy(subject,target)
    curr_dt1 = curr_dt2
```

#### Brief explanation

If the script starts up, it checks the screen's resolution. It then checks once per second what is the current workspace, and sees if there was a workspace *switch*. If so, it copies the links that you placed in the corresponding folder in `~/desktop_data` to your desktop, and removes the links that are not.

#### Important note

In your localized version of Ubuntu, `Desktop` might be named differently ("Bureaublad" in Dutch for example). If so, change in the script the line:

```
desktop_dir = home+"/"+"Desktop"
```

to reflect your localized name of the `Desktop` folder.

Comment: thanks so much . Is there a way to improve it and include launchers ?

Comment: @EliasAlves absolutely! I will edit the answer this weekend. I actually removed the option because I thought you only wanted the folder shortcuts :)

Comment: @EliasAlves Hi Elias, added the launchers-per-workspace option. Just an idea, but having a distinguished Unity launcher per workspace would be a relatively small addition. It wouldn't make the script any heavier for the system (if any), since it only acts on workspace change. Would that add anything to it for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this functionality is currently not supported. You could try play with 3rd-party software like [screenlets](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/screenlets/) but I would strongly not recommend it.