# Ubuntu unique workspaces

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, libreoffice, workspaces

is it possible too have unique workspaces in Ubuntu?

For example:

1. 1st workspace:

   - Programming launcher icons
   - Programming files on desktop
2. 2nd workspace:

   - libre office launcher icons
   - words and excel files on desktop

What I want to have is unique launcher icons for every workspace and different files on my desktop for every workspace!

1. Is it possible?
2. How can I do it?

Comment: Your question is a dupe of two others. The other one will follow...

Comment: @Jacob
I have read that already but how can I do that with my files?
I thought it would be easier to find a solution if i list both things I want to do!

Comment: The other one is this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/596159/folders-and-launchers-exclusively-on-one-desktop together they should answer your question. As mentioned in the dupe link, a ppa is available for that one.

Answer (score -1):

I do not if you can do this with Unity, but PC Linux does something similar to what you want.  It places different types of icons/programs on different work spaces.  Internet on work space one, office on work space two, and so on.

Comment: Not very good answer.  OP wants this functionality in Ubuntu, but you suggest different distro.